# How does this retarget.c work

Tags: c, embedded, int, fgets, uart

Can someone explain to me how this retarget.c works? 
I am trying to send integers to and from the uart of a microcontroller, i have been successful with using fgets to get a char (16 bits) and returning an integer using the atoi function in the Uart Interupt service routine but I am trying to get an integer using scanf, i am thinking i need to change the retarget file outlined below?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <rt_misc.h>

#define AHB_LED_BASE                0x50000000
#define AHB_UART_BASE               0x51000000

#pragma import(__use_no_semihosting)

struct __FILE { 
    unsigned char * ptr;
    };

FILE __stdout =     {(unsigned char *)  AHB_UART_BASE};
FILE __stdin =      {(unsigned char *)  AHB_UART_BASE};

int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{
  return(uart_out(ch));

}

int fgetc(FILE *f)
{ 
    return(uart_in());
}

int ferror(FILE *f)
{
  return 0; 
}

int uart_out(int ch)
{
    int* UARTPtr;
    UARTPtr = (int*)AHB_UART_BASE;
    *UARTPtr = (int)ch;
    return(ch);
}

int uart_in()
{
    int ch;
    int* UARTPtr;
    UARTPtr = (int*)AHB_UART_BASE;  
    ch = *UARTPtr;
    uart_out(ch);
    return((int)ch);
}

void _ttywrch(int ch)
{ 
  fputc(ch,&__stdout); 
}

void _sys_exit(void) {


    while(1); 

}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Cortex-M0 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <rt_misc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AHB_LED_BASE                0x50000000
#define AHB_UART_BASE               0x51000000


void UART_ISR(void)
{
            int sample;

            printf("the value entered is %d\n", sample);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Function
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {

    {

        int sample;
        scanf ("%d",&sample);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function will need [`ungetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/ungetc.html) because it must scan ahead in the buffer to see when fields end. E.g., when looking for a number, it needs to pull one character after the number to see where the number ends. When it sees the non-number character, it needs to put it back into the stream so the next call to `getc` will get it.

Something like this:

```
struct __FILE
{ 
    unsigned char * ptr;
    int unchar; /* place to keep the character put back in the stream */
};

FILE __stdout =     {(unsigned char *)  AHB_UART_BASE, -1};
FILE __stdin =      {(unsigned char *)  AHB_UART_BASE, -1};

int fgetc(FILE *f)
{ 
    int c;

    if (f->unchar == -1)
    {
        c = uart_in();  /* just read a character */
    }
    else
    {
        c = f->unchar;  /* reuse the character put back by ungetc */
        f->unchar = -1; /* mark it as used */
    }
    return c;
}

int fungetc(int c, FILE *f)
{
    unsigned char uc = c; /* POSIX says that it is converted first to unsigned char */
    f->unchar = (int )uc; /* put back the character */
    return (int )uc;
}
```

Comment: More text and comments added to my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but It's still returning 0 for the code i've added below retarget.c in the main question.

Comment: The Uart ISR is activated after i enter a single character on putty/hyperterminal, should I be looking towards increasing the size of the input buffer?